# How to obtain location based on device unique ID?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, ip

Well I know this is very inefficient and can be done using Network Providers/GPS but I wanted to know whether location (latitude and longitude) can be obtained from a devices unique ID i.e. WIFI Mac Address, IP address etc.

So coding in Android Studio, I want to provide the unique ID in the code and obtain location based on the unique ID I provide.

Thanks

Comment: no, Location providers are responsible in determining your location. If your device doesn't have GPS/Network provider then how can unique Id can help you in that case?

Comment: That is my question :) In police cases, they use IMEI number to track the location of the criminals/victims. I want to know how that can be done programmatically.

Comment: They have a system to track each sim and on which device it is running. They can't track your phone even with IMEI until any sim is inserted in it.

Comment: 'a system' 
So if my phone has a sim inserted, can I programmatically obtain the location in Android Studio?

Comment: No, the company who manufactured that sim has right to track it. You can't.
It is just like that you want to recharge your sim programmatically without paying, you can't do this but the company can.

Comment: Alright. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get location from the unique ID. You can however get an approximate latitude and longitude from an IP Address by using a third party lookup service such as [IP Find](http://ipfind.co).

The location will be accurate to the city at best, will not give an exact location.

```
<?php
$request_uri = 'https://ipfind.co';
$ip_address = "8.8.8.8";
$url = $request_uri . "?ip=" . $ip_address;
$document = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($document);
?>
```

Result:

```
{
ip_address: "8.8.8.8",
country: "United States",
country_code: "US",
continent: "North America",
continent_code: "NA",
city: null,
county: null,
region: null,
region_code: null,
timezone: null,
owner: null,
longitude: -97.822,
latitude: 37.751,
currency: "USD",
languages: [
"en-US",
"es-US",
"haw",
"fr"
]
}
```